# syntax error unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, connection

Can anybody tell me what's wrong in my program? When I run this program I get the following error message:

> syntaxerror unexpected character after line continuation character

```
import sqlite3
sqlite_file = 'my_first_db.sqlite'   # NAME OF THE SQL DATABASE FILE
table_name1 = 'my_table_1'  # NAME OF THE TABLE THAT TO BE CREATED.
table_name2 = 'my_table_2'  # NAME OF THE SECOND TABLE THAT TO BE CREATED.
new_filed = 'my_1st_coulmn' # NAME OF THE COULMN
filed_type = 'INTEGER'      # COULMN DATA TYPE
# CONNECTING TO DATA BASE FILE
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c =  conn.cursor()
# CREATEING NEW SQLITE TABLE WITH 1 COULMN
c.execute('create table {tn} ({nf}) {ft})'\ .format(tn=table_name1,nf=new_filed,ft=filed_type))
# Creating a second table with 1 column and set it as PRIMARY KEY
# note that PRIMARY KEY column must consist of unique values!
c.execute('create table {tn} ({nf}) {ft} primary key)'\.format(tn=table_name2,nf=new_filed,ft=filed_type))
# Committing changes and closing the connection to the database file
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: You have no question in the body. You have not said what language this is. Where does the error happen? Please edit the question and fix it. I already fixed the formatting, please make note of that next time also.

Comment: Please add a language tag

Comment: this is python language and this line c.execute('create table {tn} ({nf}) {ft})'\ .format(tn=table_name1,nf=new_filed,ft=filed_type)) i get the error

Comment: remove  \  before .format

Answer (score 0):

\ is used for line continuation while writing long queries.
so  just remove \ before .format() at creation and execution of query if you continued the code after .

```
  # CREATEING NEW SQLITE TABLE WITH 1 COULMN
    c.execute('create table {tn} ({nf}) {ft})'.format(tn=table_name1,nf=new_filed,ft=filed_type))
```

and for more info read this.. https://pyformat.info/